# How the name "craqueuhhe" is read

Tags: prononciation

Can anybody kindly tell me how this name is read: a craqueuhhe, a kind of necrophageous vampire from France. I know how to read the beginning craqueu- Is the ending pronounced -hhe?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am not sure but i guess that **craqueu** and **craqueuhhe** will be pronounced the same way. the `-hhe` should not affect the way of how to pronounce the word imho

Comment: According to the French sources, the Craqueuhhe feeds on live children which makes him more of a pedophagous monster than a necrophagous one.  Just out of curiosity, how did you come across the Craqueuhhe?

Comment: Translating a book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ce mot n'obéit pas aux règles habituelles orthographiques du français : on n'a jamais de double H. Un français comme moi qui ne connaît pas ce mot hésiterait sur sa prononciation. Avec un seul H entre deux voyelles, on prononce les deux voyelles séparément (je ne crois pas que la séparation soit exactement un [coup de glotte](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coup_de_glotte), mais elle s'en rapproche), et ce même s'il s'agit de voyelles identiques : *Sahara* [sa.a.ʁa], *nihilisme* [ni.i.lism], *véhément* [ve.e.mɑ̃]... Le groupe `euhe` n'apparaît jamais en français, mais je prononcerais les deux voyelles normalement : [ø] pour `eu` suivi de [ə] (éventuellement réalisé [œ]) pour `e` qui ne peut pas être muet à cause du `h`. Donc en me basant uniquement sur l'orthographe, je prononcerais [kʁa.kø.ə], voire [kʁa.kø.hə] puisque s'il y a deux H ils doivent bien compter pour quelque chose.

Il s'avère que c'est un mot de patois [Lorrain](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorraine) et plus particulièrement [Mosellan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moselle_(d%C3%A9partement)). On le trouve dans [*Le Livre secret des vampires* by Katherine Quenot](https://booknode.com/le_livre_secret_des_vampires_0561902) ([retranscription](http://creaturedelamort.e-monsite.com/pages/les-vampires-du-monde/les-vampires-francais.html)) ainsi que dans le le [*Dictionnaire des patois romans de la Moselle*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/dictionnaire-des-patois-romans-de-la-moselle/oclc/316428511) (Léon Zéliqzon, 1922–1924), [vol. 1 p. 171](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedesp01zl/page/170). Ce dernier donne une indication de prononciation.

> Craqueuhhe [krakœ ̢χ M, N], s. m.
>
> — Monstre fabuleux.

« M, N » [signifie](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedesp01zl/page/n21) que le mot vient de la rive droite de la [Moselle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moselle_(rivi%C3%A8re)) au nord-ouest de [Metz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metz), et de la vallée de la [Nied](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nied) (voir carte après [p. VII](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedesp01zl/page/n17)). Le guide de prononciation ([p. XV](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedesp01zl/page/n25)) explique :

> [œ ̢] = *eu* français ouvert : *chal**eu**r*. *(donc [œ] en IPA)*
>   * [χ] est une [fricative](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_fricative) [vélaire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_v%C3%A9laire) qui se prononce à peu près comme dans le mot allemand *Bach*. *(donc un R dur, et pas [k] comme on prononce « Bach » en français)*

La prononciation correcte en français est donc quelque chose comme **[kʁa.kœx]**, qu'on aurait tendance à approximer par [kʁa.kœʁ] puisqu'il n'y a pas de fricative vélaire en français. Bref, c'est à peu près ce que l'on écrirait « *<s>craqueur</s> ».

---

This word doesn't obey normal French spelling rules (you can't have a double H), so a French person who doesn't know the word (which was my case until now) would hesitate on how to pronounce it. With a single H between two vowels, both vowels are sounded with a syllable break between them (I don't think it's an actual [glottal stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop), but close). Even if the vowels are identical, they don't merge: *Sahara* [sa.a.ʁa], *nihilisme* [ni.i.lism], *véhément* [ve.e.mɑ̃]... The group `euhe` never appears in French, but I'd pronounce it with a normal [ø] for the `eu` followed by a [[ə](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel)] which may be realized as [œ] and which the `h` makes mandatory (contrast *queue* [kø] where the final `e` is always silent). Thus my uninformed pronunciation, guessed from the spelling, is [kʁa.kø.ə], or possibly [kʁa.kø.hə] on the basis that if the `h` is present twice it must be important.

It turns out that this is a word from [Lorraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorraine) and more specifically from [Moselle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moselle_(department)). There is a description in
[*Le Livre secret des vampires* by Katherine Quenot](https://booknode.com/le_livre_secret_des_vampires_0561902) ([copied on the web](http://creaturedelamort.e-monsite.com/pages/les-vampires-du-monde/les-vampires-francais.html)) and in the [*Dictionnaire des patois romans de la Moselle*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/dictionnaire-des-patois-romans-de-la-moselle/oclc/316428511) (Léon Zéliqzon, 1922–1924) which provides a pronunciation indication. There is a [copy on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedesp01zl/), the word is on [page 171](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedesp01zl/page/170).

> Craqueuhhe [krakœ ̢χ M, N], s. m.
>
> — Monstre fabuleux.

“M, N” means the word was recorded in the east bank of the [Moselle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moselle) north-west of [Metz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metz), and the [Nied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nied) valley (See “[Introduction](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedesp01zl/page/n21)” and [map](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedesp01zl/page/n17)). The [pronunciation key](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedesp01zl/page/n25) explains:

- [œ ̢] is a [mid-front rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_front_rounded_vowel), i.e. [œ] in IPA, like the French semi-closed *eu* in *chaleur*.
- [χ] is a [velar fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_fricative) which is close but not identical to the [voiceless velar fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative) as in the German *Bach* or the Scottish *loch*.

Thus the correct pronunciation in French would be something like [kʁa.kœx], possibly approximated as [kʁa.kœʁ] since French doesn't have a velar fricative.

Answer (score 4):

We find in Léon Zéliqzon's *Dictionnaire des patois romans de Moselle* (1922) the following entry (https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedesp01zl/page/171) :

Craqueuhhe /krakœχ/ : (patois messin, patois de la Nied) (s.m.) - Monstre fabuleux.

/χ/ is described by Zéliqzon as *une fricative vélaire qui se prononce à peu près comme* ch *dans le mot allemand* Bach.

Here's some more info on the Craqueuhhe :

Etre fantastique ressemblant assez bien à Croquemitaine... Ses lieux de repaire étaient les bois, les puits, les anciennes carrières de pierres, en somme tout endroit interdit aux enfants. Le Craqueuhhe avait d'énormes mâchoires, des dents de loup et une barbe en broussaille. A la tombée du jour, il quittait sa retraite mystérieuse et se rapprochait des habitations. Il guettait les enfants désobéissants qui s'attardaient sur les routes et dans les prés, les pourchassait,
les attaquait et les croquait à belles dents.

If you see one, run for your life!

Comment: Thanks,  I agree that there should be "oe ", not "a", something like in "girl" perhaps. You have been very helpful.